# How to monitor File History on Windows 8.1 / 10 remotely?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, powershell, file-history

We are using File History feature in Windows 8.1 and 10 on the machines. It's been working well.

Is there anyway from the administrator point of view (remotely) that can monitor this activity whether is running/updated or not via powershell or anything.

At the moment, we only checked the last modified date in Config1.xml in the actual file history backup - {machine_name}/Configuration/Config1.xml. If it's current date and time means ok.

I'm appreciated your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "At the moment, we only checked the last modified date in Config1.xml in the actual file history backup" - is this your check if the feature works well? Do you already do this with PowerShell or are you doing this manually? Whats the output you want to get from PowerShell?

Comment: As I said, the only way to monitor this is by looking at Config1.xml file modified date on the actual remote backup. In our case, the file history is backup to remote device. If it's current means ok. We don't know how what is the best approach on this. That why we need some inputs ie. Powershell etc etc. What we need to know from PowerShell it's actually saying that the file history went ok at this xxx date and time.

Comment: how is the date written in the files? can you paste the "date" line of the config here?

Comment: The date is not appearing inside xml item configuration on the config1.xml file but only as "Date Modified" for that file.

Comment: can you please just paste this whole line of the config in here? something like `<date>Date Modified</date>` ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open up Control Panel
2. Click on "File History"
3. Under the little drive icon, it says when it last backed up.

If you want, you can drag the "File History" icon to the desktop (creating a shortcut) so you can check it more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I built a small tool, which calls an HTTP address whenever there was a change in the Configuration folder of the backup. Thus it is possible to hook it to healthchecks.io or similar for an overview page or E-Mail/Instant Messaging alerts.
You can either run the script on your server manually or use the docker container that comes with it.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/nicjak/fhmonitor/)

[Docker Hub Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nicjak/fhmonitor)